# how to send put request with data as an xml element, from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, put

My data is an xml element & I want send PUT request with JavaScript. How do I do this ?

For reference : [Update Cell](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#UpdatingCells)

**EDIT :**
As per fredrik suggested, I did this :

```
<form id="submitForm" method="PUT" enctype="application/atom+xml" action="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1">
            <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006'>
                <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1</id>
                <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1'/>
                <gs:cell row='2' col='1' inputValue='300'/>
            </entry>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

However, it doesn't write back but positively it returns xml file like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
    <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1</id>
    <updated>2011-01-11T07:35:09.767Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' term='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell'/>
    <title type='text'>A2</title>
    <content type='text'></content>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1'/>
    <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq69FHX3TV4ndDBDVFFETUFhamc5S25rdkNoRkd4WXc/od6/private/full/R2C1/1ekg'/>
    <gs:cell row='2' col='1' inputValue=''></gs:cell>
</entry>
```

Here, inputvalue is empty ! However, it is 300 in my xml string.
Any further solution for the same ?

Comment: Please check the link, which says that I want to write back to spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the HTTP protocol only supports sending string I'm un sure if you are able to do this. But what you could try is using [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and changing the method to PUT and content type and send a serialized XML.

The jQuery documentation says:

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Invoke a ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: 'text/xml',
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Hope it works.

**EDIT**:
Please provide some more information/code on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks fredrik, but i want this same without AJAX.

Comment: It is the same that is given on the link I have provided.

Comment: How would you do it otherwise? "I want send PUT request with JavaScript". If you don't use AJAX it's a normal html-post. Where do you have your XML data?

Comment: Oh ! but, google doesn't support the cross domain request. If it is not possible without AJAX, I cannot write back :(

Comment: Well, from what I understand (never used the service) you parse your XML to a string. And insert in a input field. Then set `method="PUT"` in your form element.