# Correct syntax for Google Spreadsheet update - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Anybody know the correct syntax for updating a row in Google Spreadsheets using the Javascript API?

I'm working off of the API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_a_list_row) and I can't figure out what is the correct syntax I need to send the data in.  What I have currently is:

```
var serialObject = $('#basicForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
        url: updateBasicUrl,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: serialObject,
    });
```

What should the syntax of the data field be (the above throws an unidentifiable error)?

EDIT - after converting a JSON object to XML to conform to the exact look of the xml [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_a_list_row), it still doesn't work:

```
var updateBasicUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/*spreadsheetIDnumber*/od6/private/full/*cellID*/*versionnumber*?access_token=*accesstoken*
$.ajax({
        url: updateBasicUrl,
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/atom+xml',
        //contentType: 'text/xml',  //tried both of these, they don't seem to work
        data: xmlBasic,
    })
```

EDIT - So it seems there is a Cross-Domain Origin problem.  The Google Spreadsheets API won't allow it.  Anybody know of a work-around?

Comment: can you give more details. i.e. your OAuth token. what is your updateBasicUrl etc. ... I set my Oauth like this  spreadsheetService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

Comment: Not sure why you would need my OAuth token.  It's working fine as I can download from the Spreadsheet just fine, just not upload (and I'm not getting a Permission Denied error either).

Answer (score 0):

you could search the java source code for the solution - http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService.java?r=94

this triggers the send in the java version:
service.insert(cellFeedUrl, newEntry);

```
public void setCell(int row, int col, String formulaOrValue)
    throws IOException, ServiceException {

  CellEntry newEntry = new CellEntry(row, col, formulaOrValue);
  service.insert(cellFeedUrl, newEntry);
  out.println("Added!");
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to convert that to a Javascript request.  I also think the API requires different things from the Javascript PUT request and the Java request (though since I can't really understand the Java, I don't know for sure).

Comment: I expect the request data will be the same. Is your request from the browser? I understand OAuth in the browser is not quite the same. ...  here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669281/how-to-send-put-request-with-data-as-an-xml-element-from-javascript